# How to renew a jar signature?

Tags: jar-signing, jarsigner

Warning: 
The signer certificate has expired.

I get the following when I try to sign with jarsigner, and the output jar doesn't get generated.

How do I renew my jar signature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using a self-signed certificate?  If so, you just need to use keytool to generate a new certificate, then sign your jar using keysigner.

If you are using a third-party signed certificate (Verisign, Thawte, etc), you'll need to renew your key using their online system (usually the same place you got the original cert).

Comment: it's my own. But will those that marked it as trusted notice any difference? It looks to as if you are saying to just make a new one.

Comment: apparently a jar signature cannot be 'renewed'.